# OpenCv approxPolyDP: What does the `closed` parameter do?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, opencv

What does the `closed` parameter actually do in `approxPolyDP`?

I think I know what it *means* (set to true if your shape is closed, false if not). But how does the function actually use this param?

After playing around for awhile, I can't seem to find a case where the value of this param actually makes a difference.

Any source code pointers would be appreciated.

I have already seen [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga0012a5fdaea70b8a9970165d98722b4c).

Comment: What Language are you running?

Comment: Python mostly, and sometimes I call this function in C++ too